# App Script not updating Doc to include existing data on Form edits

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs, google-forms

I've been working on the process of auto populating a form based on a Google form submission.  All of my progress to date has been what I learned on this site.  Thanks for all the help!

I got everything to work exactly how it needed to run, assuming that the form is filled out in its entirety.  The technician fills out the google form and submits. After he/she submits, the script automatically generates a custom document with all the data.

After some runtime, the technicians asked that we make the Google Form editable after submission.  I did some research and found that you can make a form editable and wrote some script to auto generate a custom URL for each form.

Now I'm running into an issue with the auto Doc when partial forms are submitted.  If the technician fills out the 1'st half of the form and submits, a Doc is auto generated with only the 1st half data, which I expected.  Now if they go back and fill out the 2nd half of the form, only the 2nd portion of the Doc is filled out.  I thought it would pull the entire row of data from the Sheet, but this isn't the case.

After some thought, I think I need to rewrite the code to **not** auto generate the Doc when a form is submitted, because more and more forms will be filled out in pieces, and completed at a later date.

Here's is what I would like to do.  Any insight or helpful links would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks so much!

All of the form data currently goes to the Sheet, Tab A.  I would have a second Tab B on the sheet named "Data to Doc".  I would manually comb through Tab A and copy and past the data to Tab B that I would like to create Doc's for.  On Sheet B, There would be a button that I can click that would run the script to convert the sheet data to a Doc file.

I found a video of what I think I want to do, but I cant seem to make my code work the way they did.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r9uU_KwGgzQ

Below is my current code.

```
var docTemplate = "fdgfdg"; 
var docName = "Technician Report";
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('hjhjghhgjgh');

function onFormSubmit(e) {
var replaceTextToImage = function(body, searchText, fileId) {
 var width = 300; // Please set this.
 var blob = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getBlob();
 var r = body.findText(searchText).getElement();
 r.asText().setText("");
 var img = r.getParent().asParagraph().insertInlineImage(0, blob);
 var w = img.getWidth();
 var h = img.getHeight();
 img.setWidth(width);
 img.setHeight(width * h / w);
}

//Get information from form and set as variables
var Technician = e.values[1];
var Customer_Name = e.values[2];
var Date = e.values[3];
var Facility_Location = e.values[4];
var WO_Project_No = e.values[5];
var PO_No = e.values[6];
var Tag_No = e.values[7];
var Site_Contact = e.values[8];
var Repair_Scope = e.values[9];
var Valve_Serial_No = e.values[10];
var Valve_Model = e.values[11];
var Valve_Condition = e.values[12];
var Valve_Action = e.values[13];
var Act_Serial_No = e.values[14];
var Act_Model = e.values[15];
var Act_Condition = e.values[16];
var Act_Action = e.values[17];
var Cont_Serial_No = e.values[18];
var Cont_Model = e.values[19];
var Cont_Condition = e.values[20];
var Cont_Action = e.values[21];
var Recommended_Actions = e.values[30];
var Call_Notes = e.values[32];
var Picture1_Notes = e.values[23];
var Picture2_Notes = e.values[25];
var Picture3_Notes = e.values[27];
var Picture1_Image = e.values[22].split("=")[1];
var Picture2_Image = e.values[24].split("=")[1];
var Picture3_Image = e.values[26].split("=")[1];



// Get document template, copy it as a new temp doc, and save the Doc’s id
var copyId = DriveApp.getFileById(docTemplate)
.makeCopy(docName+' for '+Customer_Name+' '+Tag_No, folder)
.getId();  
 // Open the temporary document
var copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId);
// Get the document’s body section
var copyBody = copyDoc.getBody();


copyBody.replaceText('A1', Technician);
copyBody.replaceText('A2', Customer_Name);
copyBody.replaceText('A3', Date);
copyBody.replaceText('A4', Facility_Location);
copyBody.replaceText('A5', WO_Project_No);
copyBody.replaceText('A6', PO_No);
copyBody.replaceText('A7', Tag_No);
copyBody.replaceText('A8', Site_Contact);
copyBody.replaceText('A9', Repair_Scope);
copyBody.replaceText('B1', Valve_Serial_No);
copyBody.replaceText('B2', Valve_Model);
copyBody.replaceText('B3', Valve_Condition);
copyBody.replaceText('B4', Valve_Action);
copyBody.replaceText('B5', Act_Serial_No);
copyBody.replaceText('B6', Act_Model);
copyBody.replaceText('B7', Act_Condition);
copyBody.replaceText('B8', Act_Action);
copyBody.replaceText('B9', Cont_Serial_No);
copyBody.replaceText('C1', Cont_Model);
copyBody.replaceText('C2', Cont_Condition);
copyBody.replaceText('C3', Cont_Action);
copyBody.replaceText('C4', Recommended_Actions);
copyBody.replaceText('C5', Call_Notes);
copyBody.replaceText('C8', Picture1_Notes);
copyBody.replaceText('D1', Picture2_Notes);
copyBody.replaceText('D3', Picture3_Notes);
replaceTextToImage(copyBody, 'C7', Picture1_Image);
replaceTextToImage(copyBody, 'C9', Picture2_Image);
replaceTextToImage(copyBody, 'D2', Picture3_Image);


copyDoc.saveAndClose();
```

Comment: What do you think about generating the doc only under the conditions that the form has been completed, that is all questions have been answered?

Comment: @ziganotschka I think that would work also!

Comment: thanks for the response @ziganotschka. Is there a specific place I should place this?  Do I need to add anything else?  I tried to add it and it didnt work.  Again, I apologize I don't really know what I'm doing, trying to learn!

Comment: You need to incorporate the rest of your code inside the if statement. So `if(e.response.getItemResponses().length == length){var replaceTextToImage = function(body, searchText, fileId) {...copyDoc.saveAndClose();}else{   
    Logger.log("Form is not complete");
  }
`  -provide your code works - I did not test.

Comment: The only thing I noticed is that you use `e.values` which makes me believe that your script is bound to a spreadsheet, instead of a form - spreadsheet and Form `onSubmit` triggers have different event objects. The script sample I gave you needs to be bound to a form, so it will not recognize. `e.values`. Instead, replace `e.values[1]` by `e.response.getItemResponses()[0].getResponse()` etc.

Comment: Thanks again @ziganotschka!  I'm still trying to rack my brain around how to make this work.  I now realize that having this trigger to run only when all the fields are filled out wont work, because often times there are fields that may not apply.  Ahh this stuff is hard, but it is fun!  I'll keep at trying to make it work!  It seems like having a cell in the sheet be a checkbox, and an admin can check which reports to run may be a way to do it.

Comment: Is there any way to know in advance which fields apply and which do not need to be filled out? If not, then the way with the checkbox would indeed be the easiest, if you don't mind that someone needs to check it.

Comment: @ziganotschka The checkbox is probably the easiest way to do this.  Again I apologize for all the questions, but can you point me in the right direction on how to modify my code to accomplish this?    Everything in my code works perfectly assuming the user submits all the data initially.  If I could get a button on my sheet that says "convert data to DOC" and add a column with a checkbox. That would solve my isssue.  I feel like I'm close yet so far away haha.

Comment: I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a script bound to your Form with an `onSubmit` trigger, you can retrieve the length of the latest response and comprare it to the total amount of questions:

```
function myFunction(e) {
  var length = FormApp.getActiveForm().getItems().length;
    if(e.response.getItemResponses().length == length){
    //proceed to generate custom document
  }else{   
    Logger.log("Form is not complete");
  }
}
```

### UPDATE: Alternative solution create doc if checkbox has been checked

- In this case, you do not want to run the function when the form is submitted, but when an edit of the checkbox has been made.
- So, replace the `onSubmit` trigger through an `onEdit` trigger.
- This will alow you to access the event objects `e.range`, `e.oldValue` and `e.value`.
- You  can implement an `if` statement that runs the code only if an edit in the checkbox column has been made and if the old value was `false (unchecked) and the new one is`true` (checked).
- Unfortunately you cannot retrieve your form response `onEdit` with `e.values`, instead, you can verify in which row the checkbox has been checked and retrieve the values of this row with `sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();`
- To implement the change, create a column with checkboxes (lets say in column 29, since the columns before are ocupied with responses) and mofify your code as following:

```
function onEdit(e){
  if(e.range.getColumn() == 29 || e.oldValue == false && e.value == true){
    var row = e.range.getRow();
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    var values = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    var replaceTextToImage = function(body, searchText, fileId) {
      var width = 300; // Please set this.
      var blob = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getBlob();
      var r = body.findText(searchText).getElement();
      r.asText().setText("");
      var img = r.getParent().asParagraph().insertInlineImage(0, blob);
      var w = img.getWidth();
      var h = img.getHeight();
      img.setWidth(width);
      img.setHeight(width * h / w);
    }

    //Get information from form and set as variables
    var Technician = values[1];
    var Customer_Name = values[2];
   ...
   ... 
    copyDoc.saveAndClose();
  }
}
```